# Warnings and errors when updating Aptitude with multiple architectures enabled

Tags: package-management, updates, aptitude, arm, qemu

I have an Odroid XU3 with Ubuntu installed on it. I recently installed qemu-user-static for the purpose of running i386 binaries.

Part of this process was adding the URLs of a repository I can download i386 binaries from to Apt. After doing so, I am getting errors like the following when I use the command "**Aptitude update**":

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/dists/wily-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages: 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.151 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://en.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-proposed/restricted/binary-armhf/Packages: 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://en.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-updates/universe/binary-armhf/Packages: 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://en.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-updates/multiverse/binary-armhf/Packages: 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://en.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-updates/main/binary-armhf/Packages: 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
E: Couldn't rebuild package cache
```

**ports.ubuntu.com** is where I download the ARM binaries from and **en.archive.ubuntu.com** is where I get the i386. I'm assuming that the errors are caused by Aptitude trying to retrieve i386 binaries from **ports.ubuntu.com** and vice-versa for the ARM binaries.

Is there a way of telling Aptitude to only get ARM binaries from **ports.ubuntu.com** and i386 only from **en.archive.ubuntu.com**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question here: https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO#Setting_up_apt_sources

To summarize, you need to open the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file with a text editor and then add `arch=<architecture>` between `deb` and the URL for each line. This is the example provided on the page:

```
deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal main universe
deb [arch=armel,armhf] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports quantal main universe
```